Total blackbody spectrum from two objects at different temperatures
I was wondering what the intensity spectrum would look like when collecting the light emitted by two objects (same material properties, emissivity etc.) at two different temperatures. Or alternatively, for a single object with a temperature gradient.
I am assuming it would simply be the superposition of both spectra added together? I know this may be a silly question, but all the information I could find online referred to the case of a single blackbody at a single temperature.

Yes you are right. It would be a superposition because electromagnetic wavs dont interact between them (electromagnetism/maxwell equations are linear)

It's not really a superposition, since that word usually refers to amplitudes (though it would work with amplitudes from two sources). It's basically the sum of each source, weight by the subtended solid angle
